# Паттерн проектирования для внутреннего приложения организаций

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Работая в вебе, я знаю только паттерн MVC - где есть пользователи сайта и его непосредственные администраторы.. Но вот возникла задача разработать веб-сервис учета оборудования на складе, каким подходом можно пользоваться для проектирования подобного рода приложения - ведь, по сути, у него нету клиентской части - всю информацию можно получить или изменить только авторизовавшись в системе.
Я в этом отношении профан, поэтому, в добавок спрошу - какие фреймвроки/библиотеки можно использовать для подобной цели (Знаю только про Django - но, как я понял, он необходим для разработки сайтов и он не очень подходит для данной цели - если нет, то подскажите почему)

Comment: Вы про [`Model-View-Controller`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) что ли? Это совсем не про то, что Вы написали.

Comment: "_у него нету клиентской части_", — есть. _Клиент_ авторизуется и отправляет на _сервер_ данные, где они заносятся в БД. Если клиентская часть планируется в виде `Web`-страницы, то можно и `Django` использовать. Но я взял бы что-нибудь попроще и реализовал бы [`REST API`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь. 1С склад:)

Comment: @Sergey тут согласен, это наиболее рационально решение) Но вопрос концептуальный, как в целом стоит подходить к разработке подобного рода продуктов?)

Comment: MVC(model-view-controller?), он и в африке MVC. И сдаётся мне, возник он задолго до веба, Во всяком случае в первую очередь не для веба.